# Access JSON object returned from POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I am performing this post request, I get a large response but nothing containing the key, this is an exmaple of a key:`{"key":"qurixofafa"}`. How do I access this JSON object?

```js
const axios = require('axios')
axios.post('http://hastebin.com/documents', {
    payload: 'test'
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

This is the response I get, from the code above. I may have skimmed over it, but I don't believe the key is within this response. The request goes through fine, but I don't get the JSON object which is present on the website itself. This may be apart of the issue but I am not sure, `GET /documents HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.19.0\r\nHost: hastebin.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n`

```js
{ status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers:
   { date: 'Sun, 13 Oct 2019 07:23:09 GMT',
     'content-type': 'text/html',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     connection: 'close',
     'set-cookie':
      [ '__cfduid=dbd454f479...; expires=Mon, 12-Oct-20 07:23:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.hastebin.com; HttpOnly' ],    
     'x-ratelimit-limit': '500',
     'x-ratelimit-remaining': '499',
     'cache-control': 'public, max-age=600',
     'last-modified': 'Fri, 05 Apr 2019 21:32:57 GMT',
     via: '1.1 vegur',
     'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
     'expect-ct':
      'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
     server: 'cloudflare',
     'cf-ray': '524f9107e890d529-MIA' },
  config:
   { url: 'http://hastebin.com/documents',
     method: 'post',
     data: '{"payload":"test"}',
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.0' },
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 0,
     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus] },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'hastebin.com',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'hastebin.com',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 14,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'hastebin.com',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'hastebin.com',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 14,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     _header:
      'GET /documents HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.19.0\r\nHost: hastebin.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/documents',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [TLSSocket],
        connection: [TLSSocket],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        client: [TLSSocket],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'https://hastebin.com/documents',
        redirects: [] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 1,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 18,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'https://hastebin.com/documents',
        _isRedirect: true },
     [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      [Object: null prototype] { accept: [Array], 'user-agent': [Array], host: [Array] } },
  data:
   '<html>\n<head>\n<title>hastebin</title>\n<meta charset="utf-8" />\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="solarized_dark.css" />\n<link 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css" />\n<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="highlight.min.js"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="application.min.js"></script>\n<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />\n<script type="text/javascript">\n\t\t\tvar app = null;\n\t\t\t// Handle pops\n\t\t\tvar handlePop = function(evt) {\n\t\t\t\tvar path = evt.target.location.pathname;\n\t\t\t\tif (path === \'/\') { app.newDocument(true); }\n\t\t\t\telse { app.loadDocument(path.substring(1, path.length)); }\n\t\t\t};\n\t\t\t// Set up the pop state to handle loads, skipping the first load\n\t\t\t// to make chrome behave like others:\n\t\t\t// http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040\n\t\t\tsetTimeout(function() {\n\t\t\t\twindow.onpopstate = function(evt) {\n\t\t\t\t\ttry { handlePop(evt); } catch(err) { /* not loaded yet */ }\n\t\t\t\t};\n\t\t\t}, 1000);\n\t\t\t// Construct app and load initial path\n\t\t\t$(function() {\n\t\t\t\tapp = new haste(\'hastebin\', { twitter: true });\n\t\t\t\thandlePop({ target: window });\n\t\t\t});\n\t\t</script>\n</head>\n<body>\n<ul id="messages"></ul>\n<div id="key">\n<div id="pointer" style="display:none;"></div>\n<div id="box1">\n<a href="/about.md" class="logo"></a>\n</div>\n<div id="box2">\n<button class="save function button-picture">Save</button>\n<button class="new function button-picture">New</button>\n<button class="duplicate function button-picture">Duplicate & Edit</button>\n<button class="raw function button-picture">Just Text</button>\n<button class="twitter function button-picture">Twitter</button>\n</div>\n<div id="box3" style="display:none;">\n<div class="label"></div>\n<div class="shortcut"></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div id="linenos"></div>\n<pre id="box" style="display:none;" class="hljs" tabindex="0"><code></code></pre>\n<textarea spellcheck="false" style="display:none;"></textarea>\n</body>\n</html>\n' }
```

This is an example of the POST request on the website itself.

```js
Request URL: https://hastebin.com/documents
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 104.24.121.66:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 524f...
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/json
date: Sun, 13 Oct 2019 07:31:02 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
status: 200
via: 1.1 vegur
x-ratelimit-limit: 500
x-ratelimit-remaining: 499
:authority: hastebin.com
:method: POST
:path: /documents
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 4
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
cookie: __cfduid=dd39d5b7c126774b...
origin: https://hastebin.com
referer: https://hastebin.com/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0...
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
test
```

Comment: "but nothing containing the key" What key? `res` in `then(res)` should be the result being returned. What's the console output there?

Comment: I'll paste the result, one moment.

Comment: Can you give an idea of what's the response you're expecting?

Comment: `{"key":"qurixofafa"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
const axios = require('axios')
axios.post('https://hastebin.com/documents', {
    payload: 'test'
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
    console.log(`key: ${res.data.key}`)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```